# Do NSURLConnections belong in my model or controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Say I'm using a **JSON** or **XML** API to get data about my projects from a URL using an asyncronous NSURLConnection, parsing that into an **NSMutableArray** and then populating an **NSTableView**.

I have a model: **Project** 
I have a controller: **TableViewController** (acting as table data source and delegate)

Where should I put the code that starts the request and parses the result into a **NSMutableArray**.

Should I have:

1:

A method inside Project called `-(NSMutableArray* ) getAllProjects` and call this from my Controller.

Or 2:

Should I enumerate an **NSMutableArray** of **Project*** objects, called for instance **ProjectsArray*** inside my Controller; each time calling `[[Project alloc] init]`?

Option 1 makes much more sense to me because I might want to get all the projects from multiple controllers and this would save repeating code, I only need to call a public method inside my Project model. In this case would I be doing lots of `[[self alloc] init]` statements? Is this ok? Also my model would need to be an **NSURLConnection** delegate. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question.  :-)  Hiding the source of the data or its preparation is a useful behavior of the model.  Of course, the "model" doesn't have to be only one class and, from what you describe, a `ProjectManager` object might be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No doubt it must be in your Model.**

Reason :

Because you will be requiring to update it many times from different controllers, you can use KVO for that in future.

Comment: With respect I disagree. Model classes are meant to encapsulate data an perform operations on it. Operations as complex and time-consuming as network access and marshaling belong outside in controller or utility classes.

Comment: @psoft: it depends on our design :) People were doing similar stuffs much before MVC was designed, so it is upto us.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I think the good way is to have the parsing routines in the model (ProjectsArray) and connection stuff in another class, which initiates the connection and returns raw NSData (through a delegate for example), which you pass to the model to parse it. This way your model or viewController won't have multiple roles.

As for calling `[[Project alloc] init]` each time you need the data—you can use static reference in the model class and then getting it by something like `- (ProjectsArray *)instance`

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * UITableViewController has the word "controller" in it but that
 * does not make it a controller... it's a view. Pure and simple.
 *
 * /This/ is a controller...
 */

@implementation MyController 

@synthesize data; // assume readonly @property in interface

-(void)fetchData {

   NSURLConnection *connection;

   // Set up URL connection, etc. Speaking very loosely, and
   // lossing over some important threading details...

   NSURLResponse *response = GetResponse();

   NSError *__autoreleasing error;

   @autoreleasepool {
      // build objects. premature optimization is the root of all evil,
      // but if you're really worried about too much allocation, you
      // can resist duplication with custom logic in parse().
      self.data = parse([response data], &error);
   }

   if (data == nil) {
     // Error notification
   }

   else { // Success notification
      NSNotification *didFetch = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"didFetch" object:self.data userInfo:nil];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(postNotification:) withObject:didFetch waitUntilDone:NO];
   }
}

@end




@interface MyTableViewController ()
   @property (unsafe_unretained) MyController *controller;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dataView;
@end

@implementation MyTableViewController

@synthesize controller = _controller;
@synthesize dataView = _dataView;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
   _controller = [MyController controller]; // singleton
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(updateData:)
                                                name:@"didFetch"
                                              object:nil];
}


-(IBAction)buttonPress {
   [_controller fetchData]; // again, I'm glossing over threading details...
}

-(void)updateData {
   // Controller owns the data, we just get a view of it here.
   self.dataView = [[_controller data] arrayOfSomeSort];
   [self.view reloadData];
}

@end
```